# How to create an image hover overlay fade in

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is create an image hover overlay fade in so when you hover over the image, the image is dark with a black opaque film on it with the words. When you move your mouse off of it, it's just an image. Right now, I just have four images with the words on top.

```html
<div id="about-nav" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:center;
    margin-top: 130px; text-align:center; font-family:apple chancery; font-size:25px;">

    <a href="#1a" style="display:block; width:400px; height:220px; background:#ddd
    url(http://i64.tinypic.com/orqzk7.jpg); background-size:cover;
    background-position: 1px 280px; line-height:220px; margin:10px;
    text-decoration:none; color:#C5E3ED;
    text-shadow:4px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">About</a>

    <a href="#1b" style="display:block; width:400px; height:220px; background:#ddd
    url(http://i65.tinypic.com/2hyxonr.jpg); background-size:cover;
    background-position: -0.1px 260px; line-height:220px; margin:10px;
    text-decoration:none; color:#C5E3ED;
    text-shadow:4px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">Personality</a>

    <a href="#1c" style="display:block; width:400px; height:220px; background:#ddd url(http://i64.tinypic.com/pnldu.jpg); background-size:cover; line-height:220px; margin:10px; text-decoration:none; color:#C5E3ED; text-shadow:4px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">Appearence</a>

    <a href="#1d" style="display:block; width:400px; height:220px; background:#ddd
    url(http://i63.tinypic.com/2ilh8r7.jpg); background-size:cover;
    background-position: -0.1px 260px; line-height:220px; margin:10px;
    text-decoration:none; color:#C5E3ED;
    text-shadow:4px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">History</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I'm understanding your question correctly. When the image is hovered over, do you only want to see the overlay with the words or do you want to hide the overlay with the words and only see the image?

Comment: Yes, I only want to see the overlay with words. I edited my post, is that any clearer?

Comment: I don't see your attempt. Image rollovers have been around since the 90s and are well documented. Which approach have you tried?

Comment: I would suggest that you move to an embedded or external stylesheet. Inline styles are a recipe for frustration.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will defiantly take that into consideration. I'm honestly not entirely sure how to do the image roll over. I researched it online but I get lost and confused on how to convert it all into one code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this? If I understood you correctly.

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
}

figure > img {
  width: 100%;
}

figure > figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 30%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

figure:hover > figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://www.nps.gov/cari/learn/nature/images/IMG_7245-Oak-Allee-Gate.jpg?maxwidth=650&autorotate=false" alt="Nature photo">
  <figcaption>Nature photo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

*Edit* With links (to google as example)

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
}

figure > img {
  width: 100%;
}

figure > figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 30%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

figure > figcaption > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

figure:hover > figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://www.nps.gov/cari/learn/nature/images/IMG_7245-Oak-Allee-Gate.jpg?maxwidth=650&autorotate=false" alt="Nature photo">
  <figcaption>
    <a href="http://google.com">Nature photo</a>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I'm looking for. I just don't know how to do that in addition to what I have. The text so in this example "nature photo" would be linked to a separate page. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah ya answered while I was typing and realized mine's pretty much the exact same except using background-image instead of img, will del mine.

Comment: @Silk I've added a second example where the "Nature photo" is a link to another site.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!